# Ruby 2.00 compiling error on BBB

Tags: ruby, ssl, compilation, makefile, beagleboneblack

i'm try to compile ruby 2.00 on BBB.

I've downloaded source pkg from http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.0/ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.gz

next i've extract it, and i've made:

autoconf         -OK
./configure      -OK
make             -errors

```
ossl_ssl.c:116:1: error: 'TLSv1_2_method' undeclared here (not in a function)
ossl_ssl.c:117:1: error: 'TLSv1_2_server_method' undeclared here (not in a function)
ossl_ssl.c:118:1: error: 'TLSv1_2_client_method' undeclared here (not in a function)
ossl_ssl.c:122:1: error: 'TLSv1_1_method' undeclared here (not in a function)
ossl_ssl.c:123:1: error: 'TLSv1_1_server_method' undeclared here (not in a function)
ossl_ssl.c:124:1: error: 'TLSv1_1_client_method' undeclared here (not in a function)
make[2]: *** [ossl_ssl.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-2.0.0-p247/ext/openssl'
make[1]: *** [ext/openssl/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-2.0.0-p247'
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

Problem, seem related to TLS or SSL?
Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok compile ruby 2.0.0 require openssl-dev library